# Navigating a to-many relationship with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

**How do I navigate a Core Data to-many relationship in Objective-C?**

I have an `Event` model and each instances has many `EventOccurace` objects that are exposed via an `occurances` [sic] relationship. Apple's docs say that the [standard property accessor should be available](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001803-SW3) but I keep getting compile-time errors:

[image]

DetailViewController.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSSet * foo;

    foo = [[self detailItem] occurances];
    ///No known instance method for selector 'occurances'

    foo = self.detailItem.occurances;
    ///Property 'occurances' not found on object of type 'id'


    //try casting to NSManagedObject to access
    NSManagedObject * casted = (NSManagedObject *)self.detailItem;

    foo = casted.occurances;
    ///Property 'occurances' not found on object of type 'NSManagedObject *'

    foo = [casted occurances];
    ///No visible @interface for 'NSManagedObject' declares the selector 'occurances'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the (dynamically created) accessor methods, you have to create subclasses of `NSManagedObject` for your entities.

This is easily done in Xcode: Select the entities in the model editor and choose "Editor -> Create NSManagedObject subclass ..." from the menu. Include the header files (Event.h, EventOccurance.h) in your source code. Then

```
Event *event = self.detailItem;
NSSet *foo = event.occurances;
```

should work.

Alternatively, you can use Key-value coding:

```
NSSet *foo = [[self detailItem] valueForKey:@"occurances"];
```

which works even without the managed object subclasses.

Comment: I tried the `valueForKey` approach as well but apparently I got the syntax wrong. I reread the Apple docs and I dont think they made it clear that the classes needed to be triggered manually. Thanks! This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Some things that could be not working:

First of all check that your ManagedObject classes have been generated.

Second, you should specify the type of the detailItem somewhere. Or in the .h, or by casting it to a type in the .m. Now its just an "id", the compiler cant know which is its type.

Third, this is one possible way of accesing it:

```
NSArray * occurances = [self.detailItem.occurances allObjects];
for(EventOccurance * ocu in occurances){
    //blablabla
}
```

Comment: In fact, I wasnt generating them at all. I was under the impression that the classes were automagically generated by Xcode. This is helpful. Thanks!